# Test case fails in Jenkins, succeeds in Katalon Studio

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

When I launch a test case from Katalon Studio it succeeds but when I launch it in Jenkins it fails because it says that it can't find a button. Is that because Jenkins doesn't open the browser so no elements can be found?

Comment: I would need more details. Are you using the Katalon Studio plugin? I did not have good results with it, so I just called katalon.exe from the command line. Either way, please provide some information on your test and the parameters you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Because I was using Jenkins as a windows service, and window services cannot access the UI and my tests involve interacting with the UI. Therefore Jenkins should be launched using the file jenkins.war and java 8 (9 is not yet supported)

Answer (score 1):

make sure to set the same resolution local X server

```
wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', screen: '1440x900x24']) {
  // execute selenium tests
}
```

Should work.